# How to reduce a RDS user's vhdx?

Tags: remote-desktop-services, rds, vhdx

In order to reduce RDS user's vhdx (User Profile Disks) size, I wanted to test disk2vhd to rebuild a vhdx from mounted vhdx. But it doesn't work on virtual drive.

Optimize-VHD is not suitable for this job because it's **not** a Hyper-V env.

So, is there a way to reduce users's vhdx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install Hyper-V management tool to use Optimize-VHD, then you can use `compact vdisk` in `diskpart`: [compact vdisk | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/compact-vdisk).

```
diskpart
select vdisk file=<full path>
compact vdisk
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try this. I'm actually Optimize-Volume only.